# Formalism for calculating value of integral with jump dicontinuiy

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have the following problem
Let  $c \in (a,b)$ and $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ defined as

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\alpha  & \text{if $x \neq c$} \\
\beta & \text{if $x = c$}
\end{cases}$$
Prove $f$ is integrable over $[a,b]$ and find the value of the integral over said interval

**I already proved that the function is integrable** and intuition tells me that the value of the integral should be the same as the value the constant function in [a,b] if the jump discontinuity were removed, however I can't seem to be able to grasp what I have to do to justify that the value of the integral is indeed $\alpha$(b-a)

My idea was that since the function is integrable over [a,b] it is for [a,c) and (c,b] and then just sum the integrals but I have a knowledge gap there, I'm not sure if that is valid since our intervals are nor compacts anymore and since f(c) is not equal to the limits

Answer (score 1):

It is bounded function, so by [Lebesgue's Criterion for Riemann integrability](http://www.math.ncku.edu.tw/%7Erchen/Advanced%20Calculus/Lebesgue%20Criterion%20for%20Riemann%20Integrability.pdf) it can be calculated as usual Riemann integral on $[a,b]$